# eucalyptus Unable to load AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE

Tags: centos, eucalyptus

I have removed my previous creds and then again While geting new credentials it says: `Unable to load AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE`

```
[root@server-104 ~]# rm ~/creds/*
rm: remove regular file `/root/creds/admin.zip'? yes
rm: remove regular file `/root/creds/cloud-cert.pem'? yes
rm: remove regular file `/root/creds/euca2-admin-7d0b1e85-cert.pem'? yes
rm: remove regular file `/root/creds/euca2-admin-7d0b1e85-pk.pem'? yes
rm: remove regular file `/root/creds/eucarc'? yes
rm: remove regular file `/root/creds/iamrc'? yes
rm: remove regular file `/root/creds/jssecacerts'? yes
rm: remove regular empty file `/root/creds/sshlogin'? yes
[root@server-104 ~]# cd ~/creds/
[root@server-104 creds]# euca-get-credentials admin.zip
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/pyami/config.py:75: UserWarning: Unable to load AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE (/root/creds/iamrc)
  warnings.warn('Unable to load AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE (%s)' % full_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should still download the credential.

But for future reference, before downloading new admin credentials, try to re-login to the session or unset all the Eucalyptus related environment variables and try to download the credentials.

You should not see this warning anymore.